# Hooks or filters for `Parse.Object`?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Right now I have two sets of data: `Post` and `Images`. Every time I fetch a `Post` I'm having to do a sub-query to grab its image. I'd like to just perform that query to grab the image **every time the `Post` object is initialized**. That way every time I have a `Post` object, I know I also have access to its image. Does this make sense?

Is there any way to do this? The `initialize` function doesn't give me access to any of the object's data because it's called before it's set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `.include()` function. It allows you to name a related object via it's field and have it returned with the parent object. Like so:

```
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
query.where("author", "Mr. Lebowski");

// Include images associated with the Post
query.include("images");

query.find({
  success: function(posts) {
    // Images have been retrieved. For example:
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
      var Images = i.images; //This will be populated with no sub-query
    }    
  }
});
```

Comment: OK what about if there's no pointer to an `Image` from a `Post`. There's a data set called `Images` which pairs images and posts.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't use a relation between `Post` and `Image`, like a one-to-many or many-to-many. If you can, I'd recommend changing your db design, or suffer through multiple queries.

Comment: Well there is a many-to-many relationship going on here. There's a "join table" pairing posts and images. I can't seem to find much documentation on how to query in this case.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the join table, and why you have one? What are the purposes of posts and images that require a join table?

Comment: I take it back, I actually don't have a join table. I have an `Images` table which contains an image and a pointer to a `Post`.  Can this relationship be accessed from the `Post` object?

Comment: Unfortunately, that will require you to make a second call. I'd recommend creating a one-to-many Relation on `Post` that points to your `Images` objects. That will allow the code above to work :)

Comment: OK sounds good. I guess the takeaway here is to create a relationship on save.